# Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- MainController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an app with modals which I'm trying to call using $modalInstance. According to the other questions I've read here, I shouldn't include `ng-controller` in my template and that's exactly what I did, however it's still not working.

Here's my code:

**HTML - main page**

```
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
```

**HTML - add.html template**

```
<div ng-show="showAddModal">

    <div class="product-header">
        <div class="modal-title">Add Product Information</div>
        <div class="modal-close" ng-click="closeModal();">X</div>
    </div>

    <!-- other codes go here -->
</div>
```

**AngularJS - app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('ProductApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

**AngularJS - controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', 'ProductFactory', 'EditProductFactory', '$modalInstance',
                              function ($scope, $resource, $http, ProductFactory, EditProductFactory, $modalInstance) {

$scope.addProduct = function () {

    $scope.showAddModal = true;

    var modalOptions = {
        template: '/views/add.html',
        controller: 'AddController'
        //scope: $scope
    };

    $modal.open(modalOptions); 
}

...
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did u try to inject $modal in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$uibModal` instead of `$modalInstance` in your calling controller. And use `$uibModal.open(...)`.

In your `AddController` you can inject `$uibModalInstance`

```
angular.module('ProductApp').controller('AddController', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.close = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, but now I'm getting a `$uibModal is not defined` error. From what I understand, `$uibModalInstance` takes care of this, so there's no need for me to call `$uibModal` as well...right?

Comment: I created [a Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YK5Gga7jmX5IlNqSv4HC?p=preview) close to your example. Hope it helps.

Comment: It certainly did. Thank you for your effort! :)